# Can't get the JS script to output data on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, webforms

My code below is a simple form which takes an integer, and a yes/no radio button pair. If 'yes' is selected (the left option) then the value you entered * 0.13 should be displayed - if 'no' is selected (or neither are selected) then the value 0 should be displayed. It is not working as expected - how can I fix this problem?

```
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Калькулятор</title>
</head>


<body>

  <FORM NAME="Form1">
    <p><b>Какая у вас ЗП?</b></p>
    <INPUT TYPE="number" id="salary" class="value" placeholder="Enter an integer" />

    <p><b>Ваш подоходный налог 13%?</b></p>
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" name="Nalog" id="da" value="Yes">Да

    <INPUT TYPE="radio" name="Nalog" id="net" value="No">Нет

    <br>Посчитаем сумму налога?
    <INPUT TYPE ="button" value="Посчитать" onClick="solve();">

    <p id="result"></p>
  </form>

  <script>
    var output = document.getElementById("result");

    function solve() {
      var input = document.getElementById("salary").value;
      output.innerHTML = "";
      if (document.Form1.nalog[0].checked) {
        output.innerHTML = input * 0.13;
      } else {
        output.innerHTML = 0;
      }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The input value is a string. You need to convert it to a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues I found are as follows:

1. The script hasn't been evaluated yet so `solve` is not defined. I've used an ID on that button and added an event listener instead.
2. You should be accessing `Form1.Nalog` not `Form1.nalog` (note the capitalisation of the name attribute matters).

Here's a working demo with those changes applied:

```html
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Калькулятор</title>
</head>


<body>

  <form NAME="Form1">
    <p><b>Какая у вас ЗП?</b></p>
    <INPUT TYPE="number" id="salary" class="value" placeholder="Enter an integer" />

    <p><b>Ваш подоходный налог 13%?</b></p>
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" name="Nalog" id="da" value="Yes">Да

    <INPUT TYPE="radio" name="Nalog" id="net" value="No">Нет

    <br>Посчитаем сумму налога?
    <INPUT TYPE="button" value="Посчитать" id="submit">

    <p id="result"></p>
  </form>

  <script>
    var output = document.getElementById("result");
    var btn = document.getElementById("submit");

    btn.addEventListener("click", solve);

    function solve() {
      var input = document.getElementById("salary").value;
      output.innerHTML = "";
      if (document.Form1.Nalog[0].checked) {
        output.innerHTML = input * 0.13;
      } else {
        output.innerHTML = 0;
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```